# Calling API from CouchDB Design Doc

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cloudant

I am wondering if it is possible to make an API call from within a design doc. I have tried the code below, however I am getting the following error message.

```
{"error":"forbidden","reason":"CSRF Cookie/Header mismatch"}
```

This is the code:

```
function(head, req) {

    var id = req.query.id;
    var contactName = 'This is the new contact name!!';
    var sendString = '{"PrimaryContactName":"' + contactName + '"}';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT", <URL>, false);
    xhr.send(sendString);

    var sendStatus = xhr.status;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeing this error in particular, but `XMLHttpRequest` is something the browser gives you. That is not part of JavaScript directly, and CouchDB certainly doesn't expose that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to use AJAX from CouchDB. (it's not a web browser)

If you want changes in your database to be propagated to other data-sources, you can use the [`_changes` feed](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/changes.html). That will be a much more robust solution no matter how you slice it.